# I need to navigate each and every link in the web page and its sub pages links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium driver and using a python script to do this.Here is my code.

```
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("http://localhost:8080")
list_links = d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for i in list_links:
    print url
```

Above program is properly giving the out put as

```
https://www.w3schools.com/
https://www.ubuntu.com/
None
```

But when I compile below code:

```
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("http://localhost:8080")
list_links = d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for i in list_links:
    url=i.get_attribute('href')
    print url
    d.get(url)
```

It navigate to the first link https://www.w3schools.com/ successfully.Then it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "web_nav.py", line 20, in <module>
url=i.get_attribute('href')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 141, in get_attribute
resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 
(6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-31-
generic x86_64)
```

Here i am using ubuntu 14.04, language python and i'm using selenium web driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first get all the urls then navigate to them

```
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("http://localhost:8080")
list_links =  d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
urls = []    
for i in list_links:
    urls.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
for url in urls:
    d.get(url)
```

you could simplify this with a function

```
def get_link_urls(url,driver):
    driver.get(url)
    urls = []
    for link in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
        urls.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
    return urls

urls = get_link_urls("http://localhost:8080")
sub_urls = []
for url in urls:
    sub_urls.extend(get_link_urls(url))
```

Comment: You saved my lot of work thank you.But here it is navigating only to the links in the first page. Isn't that so?Is there a way to navigate sub pages links to a particular given depth..

Comment: Ex: Here first i am navigating first https://www.w3schools.com/ ..I need to go through the links inside this page to a given depth

Comment: I need to extend this code to save dynamic html page while navigating.Please can you help me for that